# How can I increase Medium RSS feed items count over 10?

Tags: reactjs, axios, restful-url

Currently I am using the Medium RSS feed like `https://medium.com/feed/@****`.
The result has 10 items, but I need 30 items.
How can I increase the number of feed items?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but increasing feed item count is not possible, they only have these simple RSS feed structures available:
https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/214874118-Using-RSS-feeds-of-profiles-publications-and-topics